# React Native OneSignal: User not prompted for consent on Android

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, onesignal, android-push-notification, react-native-onesignal

In my React Native app, I want to prompt the user to consent to receiving OneSignal push notifications. I have the code `OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse()`, which on iOS successfully prompts the user, but on Android it doesn't. When I test on my Android device, the device does still get registered and I can send it push notifications. But on another user's Android, they report that they can't receive notifications.

**What I Want To Know:**

1. Why does `OneSignal.promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse()` not prompt me for permission on Android the way it does on iOS?
2. Is there something I can do to make Android devices get prompted for permission, such that there won't be some devices that can't receive notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You need targeted SDK version as 33, anyways refer to https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/how-to-prompt-for-push-permissions-with-an-in-app-message && https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup .

It'll definitely help you figuring it out further.